# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method (method cannot be translated into a store expression)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm getting an exception... **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

My Entity has a table with 3 fields **A_Id** is an autonumber Integer, **TidFk** is an Integer and **AuditNotes** is a Nvarchar(Max), not Null, default ''

My Model has the following.

```
Public Class Audit

    Public Property AId As Integer
    Public Property TIdFk As Integer
    Public Property AuditNote As String

    Public Sub New()
        AId = 0
        TIdFk = 0
        AuditNote = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetAuditFor(tID)

        Dim de As New EHREntities

        Try
            Dim aud = (From a In de.Tbl_Audit
                       Where a.TidFk = tID
                       Select a).FirstOrDefault()

            If IsNothing(aud) Then
                AId = 0
                TIdFk = tID
                AuditNote = ""
            Else

                AId = aud.A_id
                TIdFk = aud.TidFk
                AuditNote = aud.AuditNote.ToString().Replace("<<", "<b>").Replace(">>", "</b>").Replace("<>", " <span class="" error"">&#8226;</span> ")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            AId = 0
            TIdFk = tID
            AuditNote = "<span class=""error"">Error! </span>" & ex.Message

        Finally
            de.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

My Controller has...

```
Function FetchAuditFor(tId As Integer) As PartialViewResult

        Dim auditNote As New Audit

        auditNote.GetAuditFor(tId)

        Return PartialView("_AuditNote", auditNote)

    End Function
```

The Class fails with the above mentioned exception from Sub GetAuditFor(tID)...

I've tried all I know to determine the reason for the exception but have failed... The exception mentions Boolean but there are no booleans... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMATEUR!...  `Public Sub GetAuditFor(tID)` should have been `Public Sub GetAuditFor(tID As Integer)`.... That's an hour of my life I won't get back!

Comment: Write `Option Strict On` at the top of your file and you will save some time in the future